Save shap.force_plot without cropping
Here is how I save my shap force plot into png:
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], X.iloc[0,:],show=False,matplotlib=True).savefig('scratch.png',format = "png",dpi = 300,bbox_inches = 'tight')
But by specifying "matplotlib" = True, my plot is extremely cluttered because of long feature decimal, long feature names all on the same line.
How can I save a clean shap force plot?
